# Drop all column levels without a name in a pandas multi-column-index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a multi-column-level dataframe. I need to drop all the column levels that don't have a name (i.e. `None`). I don't know in advance which levels are affected (if any at all).

What's a pythonic way to do this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Create a MultiIndex for the columns with None values in names
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
    ('A', 'X', 'I'),
    ('A', 'X', 'II'),
    ('A', 'Y', 'I'),
    ('A', 'Y', 'II'),
    ('B', None, 'I'),
    ('B', None, 'II'),
    ('B', 'Z', 'I'),
    ('B', 'Z', 'II'),
], names=[None, 'level_2', None])
# Create a DataFrame with random values
data = np.random.randint(0, 10, (8, 8))  # Corrected shape to match the MultiIndex
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=index)

print(df)

         A            B         
level_2  X     Y    NaN     Z   
         I II  I II   I II  I II
0        5  0  3  5   0  9  6  6
1        6  2  6  3   7  1  8  0
2        7  5  1  0   3  2  9  5
3        8  6  1  5   9  0  8  2
4        4  0  0  2   4  7  0  6
5        3  8  0  5   4  8  6  8
6        2  4  2  7   4  6  5  3
7        6  5  0  3   1  6  0  4
```

I am looking for this result:

```
level_2  X     Y    NaN     Z   
0        5  0  3  5   0  9  6  6
1        6  2  6  3   7  1  8  0
2        7  5  1  0   3  2  9  5
3        8  6  1  5   9  0  8  2
4        4  0  0  2   4  7  0  6
5        3  8  0  5   4  8  6  8
6        2  4  2  7   4  6  5  3
7        6  5  0  3   1  6  0  4
```

Comment: `df.droplevel([0, 2], axis=1)`

Comment: As mentioned, I don't know in advance which levels are affected (if any at all).

Comment: You can use the following code if you have too many layers to delete. `df.set_axis(df.columns.get_level_values(1), axis=1)`

Comment: I can't simply hard-code the levels that I want to keep/drop. I don't know these numbers in advance. I just presented a toy example. I am looking for a generalized solution.

Comment: `cols = [i for i, value in enumerate(df.columns.names) if value == None]`
Then we can find and delete the level that is None.
`df.droplevel(cols, axis=1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```py
df = df.droplevel([idx for idx, name in enumerate(df.columns.names) if name is None], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there was only one unnamed level, `df.droplevel(None, axis=1)` would work.

For more than one unnamed level, using [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
out = df.droplevel(np.where(pd.isnull(df.columns.names))[0].tolist(), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
level_2  X  X  Y  Y  NaN  NaN  Z  Z
0        0  2  8  7    1    2  3  9
1        5  3  4  4    3    6  9  7
2        5  9  1  8    1    9  9  1
3        1  2  4  0    1    2  0  1
4        9  0  5  6    1    0  0  4
5        5  9  6  6    1    8  8  6
6        7  6  7  4    8    5  7  1
7        6  2  3  7    1    7  2  8
```